# How do I merge the user account entity and account provided by jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

I'm very new to jhipster and I'm having an issue where jhipster provides me with a user account and I have an entity for user account too.
I the images I've added here you can see I've been signed in as account user. But I can access an eniity called user too.[Signed in as user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZWII.png) [The entity of user defined in my JDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSyDc.png) [What the JDL entity of user is doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYlbe.png). What I really want to do is merge the capability of what JDL defined user account is and account, ie when you sign up with my website you're able to set yourself a display name, email address, and a password. You'd also be able to have a profile pic? How would I go about setting this up?

I haven't really tried anything as I'm really new to jhipster and this is geniunley quite hard.

Comment: The user account and `User` entity are the same thing. You should be able to modify the object using the Admin > User Management screen.

Comment: @MattRaible it doesn't seem to be the same thing I have gone into the admin screen and the accounts there are different made by the user account entity. Here's my JDL code btw.


`entity Friends{
//    userID1 Integer
//    userID2 Integer
    status FriendshipStatus
}

entity UserAccount{
    displayName String
    email String
    password String
    profilePic ImageBlob
}

enum FriendshipStatus {
    PENDING,
    ACCEPTED,
    DENIED,
    BLOCKED
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Friends{userid1} to User
    Friends{userid2} to User
}`

Comment: If you're using JHipster 8, you can use `User with builtInEntity` to refer to the included `User` object. You see see [this JDL](https://github.com/mraible/jhipster8-demo/blob/main/blog.jdl) for an example.